# Adding Strings together

Tags: objective-c

Strings and totals drive me nuts.

I am trying to add rResults+bResults.

in the .h file i have

```
int rightCount;
```

in the .m file

```
rResults.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R Resultes:  %d",appDelegate.RCount];
bResults.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"B Resultes:  %d",appDelegate.BCount];
pResults.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"P Resultes:  %d",appDelegate.PCount];
fResults.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"F Resultes:  %d",appDelegate.FCount];

rightCount=rResults+bResults
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please explain _what you are trying to accomplish_, the _results_ you are seeing, and _how those results differ_ from your expectations. This post is nonsensical without that information, and I have voted to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add the values, why don't you just do `rightCount = appDelegate.RCount + appDelegate.BCount;`

Comment: I was just writing that! :P In general, this question leaves a lot to the imagination and the poster could start by explaining what rResults etc are. If these are just NSObjects he's made with some ivars (as indicated by rResults.text), adding them together makes no sense *at all*.

Comment: I am so blind in the late night...Dhhhhh  Thanks